# How execute .exe with arguments from PHP and put the output in txt file?

Tags: php, cmd, exec, exe

I have PHP file and I want to execute .exe with "arguments" and put the output in a text file.

When I do this job from windows cmd, it successfully works.

but, when I did this task in PHP, the text file is empty. I don't know if the execution works or not but the file is empty.

Here is the command line which works in windows cmd:

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide
blastdbcmd -entry $gi -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f -out $text_files_path\result.txt
```

`blastdbcmd` is the execution file `"blastdbcmd .exe"`. `result.txt` created successfully with all result from the command.

Here is my PHP code:
1st code:

```
$gi = 1000232109;
$cmd = "-entry $gi -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f";
exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe $cmd" , &$output, &$return_var);
file_put_contents("$text_files_path/result.txt", $output);  //result.txt created
echo $return_var;    // 1 is printed
```

2nd code:

```
$handle = popen('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/db/nucleotide/blastdbcmd.exe 2>&1', 'w');
$cmd = "-entry $gi -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f";
exec("$cmd" , $output);
file_put_contents("$text_files_path/mm.txt", $output); //result.txt created
echo "hello";
pclose($handle);
```

3rd code:

```
exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry $gi -outfmt %f -out $text_files_path/result.txt 2>&1"); //result.txt doesn't created
```

4th code:

```
exec("cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide && blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry $gi -outfmt %f -out $text_files_path/result.txt 2>&1"); //result.txt doesn't created
```

5th code:

```
exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c \"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe -entry $gi -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f -out $text_files_path\result.txt\" 2>&1");  //result.txt doesn't created
```

**Edit 1:**
I test this:

```
$cmd = "-entry $gi -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f";
exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe $cmd" , &$out, &$return_var);
$output = "";
echo $out;      // "Array" is printed
foreach ($out as $line) {
echo $out;      // nothing printed
echo $line;      // nothing printed
$output .= $line;
}
file_put_contents("$text_files_path/result.txt", $output);
echo $return_var // 1 is printed
```

but the result file is empty.

**I SOLVE IT :)**

```
exec("cd C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\webclient\\db\\nucleotide && blastdbcmd.exe -entry $gi -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f 2>&1",&$out, &$return_var);
```

just by replace `\` with `\\`

Thanks @budwiser for "foreach statement"
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $out is an array:

```
exec("yourcommand.exe", $out);

$output = "";

foreach ($out as $line) {
    $output .= $line;
}

file_put_contents("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\result.txt", $output);
```

**EDIT:**

Change

```
exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe $cmd", 
      &$out, &$return_var);
```

to

```
exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe $cmd 2>&1",
      &$out, &$return_var);
```

Comment: I test it now. Empty file!

Comment: I test it. also, empty.

Comment: I try to echo $out befor foreach statement, "Array" is printed. And I echo both $out and $line inside the foreach statement, nothing printed.

Comment: Also I try to put "hi" in file_put_contents("$text_files_path/result.txt", "hi"); , it put in the file which mean nothing related to file permission.